# Causing the Salesforce1 Mobile website to load instead of the desktop site

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I have a client using Microsoft Surface, running Windows 10. According to the [Salesforce site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf1_requirements.htm&type=0), one can load the mobile version of Salesforce using Microsoft Edge on Windows phones. However, we would like to load the mobile version of the site on the Microsoft Surface tablet.

For example, using Safari on iPad, when loading Salesforce, it defaults to the Salesforce1 mobile site. I'd like to do the same on Microsoft Surface.

Is there a switch or setting to force Salesforce to show the mobile web instead of the desktop web? If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: Set salesforce1 user checkbox to false for the user

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty thanks for the comment. That didn't work. Plus, it is counter-intuitive to tell Salesforce to not use Salesforce1 mobile browser app by unchecking that option. Why did you suggest this?